# Output to screen and to file at the same time to debug program

Tags: unix, pipe

If i have a program, say: `test.sh`, sometimes it is necessary to debug by watchingscreen output and killing the program when it reaches a certain point in the output. With particularly verbose output it can be useful to have this output in a file, as well as in the terminal.

**What is the best way to do this both in code and with debugging tools?**

Comment: This question should be reopened to allow other answers, such as editing the code directly, for eg. writing to a file and `std::cout` (in the case of `c++`) in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output can be piped with the following line:

```
./test.sh | tee -a Log.log
```

This will print to the screen and write the output from test.sh to Log.log.